# Where is the POST response body generated in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to understand a web app template for wordpress. They do not follow the POST/REDIRECT/GET pattern, and it's very annoying on an HTTPS website.

There is a static page with a next button on it. The next button is responsible for pulling the next section and displaying it to the user.

After analyzing data, the flow is something like this:

1. Click on "Next" button.
2. POST /section-viewer with two parameters, "next_section_id: 3451" and "hash: 345345"
3. POST responds with page HTML as its body -- which is the full page of the next section, 3451.

I have found bits and pieces of the HTML being generated, but I am not able to figure out the final response, and where/how Wordpress/PHP responds to the POST.

What I'd like to do is instead of sending the next page's HTML as the body of the POST response, is send redirect, and then redirect the user to the page that has the HTML there.

Comment: Are you referring to Pagination or things like the `<-- more -->` functionality of single posts? You're just trying to figure out how it gets the rest of the section? What are you asking?

Comment: Who is "they"? Most of WordPress core (not sure if I can say " all") does follow that pattern.

Comment: "they" are the web app template creators.

Comment: Then your question is about code we don't have. How do you expect an answer? (Even if it were on topic, which it isn't unless you've forked this "web app" and are now maintaining it). "Wordpress/PHP" doesn't "respond" to a `POST` request, except in the case of WordPress for its own forms. That is all developer code.

Comment: No, this is a basic question on how data is moved throughout php and wordpress. I've found my answer after attaching a debugger and following the function calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, anything that is `echo`d after the POST request, is sent back to the requester via the RESPONSE body.

Thus any `echo` statements issued after processing whatever was sent via the $_POST is generated and sent back. In this template's case, it would be better to re-direct the user immediately to a new page, instead of echoing contents back.